# Refactoring MFC string replacements with std::regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, stl, mfc

I am looking at the following MFC code written ~15 years ago. Obviously this is bad, `std::regex` should handle this better. I have two questions:

1. is there a way for `std::regex` to handle multiple replacements efficiently? e.g. replace both "John"->"Mary", "Bob"->"Alice" in a single pass?
2. for `strInput.Replace("-01-","-1-");` type replacements, is it the best I can do :

   ```
   regex re("(-0)([123456789])(-)"); 
   strinput = std::regex_replace(strinput, re, "-" + "$2" + "-");
   ```

Original code

```
         CString strInput = "....."; // MFC string
         strInput.Replace("-Jan-","-1-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Feb-","-2-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Mar-","-3-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Apr-","-4-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-May-","-5-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Jun-","-6-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Jul-","-7-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Aug-","-8-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Sep-","-9-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Oct-","-10-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Nov-","-11-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-Dec-","-12-");      

         strInput.Replace("-01-","-1-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-02-","-2-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-03-","-3-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-04-","-4-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-05-","-5-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-06-","-6-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-07-","-7-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-08-","-8-"); 
         strInput.Replace("-09-","-9-"); 

         strInput.Replace("-01,","-1,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-02,","-2,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-03,","-3,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-04,","-4,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-05,","-5,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-06,","-6,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-07,","-7,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-08,","-8,"); 
         strInput.Replace("-09,","-9,");
```

Comment: 1) Not with `regex_replace`. 2) Your solution looks good, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @cigien I was hoping something better/faster can be done with the proposed solution 2. Maybe somehow to replace all last 18 lines with one std::regex_replace

Comment: Doesn't your regex_replace do that?

Comment: Have you considered not doing the 2nd and 3rd replacement? All they do is spend CPU cycles for producing a string representation that's **harder** to parse, for humans and machines. Why not leave them fixed width?

Comment: You can just do `std::regex_replace(strinput, re, "-$2-");` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Eb61hY) If this doesn't do what you want, please clarify that in the question.

Comment: @IInspectable you got the best suggestion. A better custom parser is the fastest solution. Right now however, the task is to fix/refactor MFC code

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way for std::regex to handle multiple replacements efficiently? e.g. replace both "John"->"Mary", "Bob"->"Alice" in a single pass?

I don't think so.

> for `strInput.Replace("-01-","-1-");` type replacements

For the last 2 blocks, you can do:

```
std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("-0([1-9])(-|,)"), "-$1$2");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2d958b5c1bc8e1e)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for for question 2. Thank you!